# Connection refused on spring-client with docker and gradle

Tags: spring, gradle, docker, netflix-eureka, connection-refused

I build a spring-server and a spring-client with eureka on docker and I try to connect the client to the server.
When I try this in my `build.gradle`:

```
docker {
  maintainer = 'Me'
  baseImage = 'java:8'
}

distDocker {
  exposePort 8080
  setEnvironment 'JAVA_OPTS', '-Dspring.profiles.active=docker'
}
```

everything works.

But I want to use the `Dockerfile` I wrote, so I use `buildDocker` instead of `distDocker` and I use it this way:

```
task buildDocker(type: Docker, dependsOn: build) {
  dockerfile = file('src/main/docker/Dockerfile')
  doFirst {
    copy {
      from jar
      into stageDir
    }
  }
}
```

with this `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM java:8
ADD myjar-1.0.jar app.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/app.jar"]
```

and that always leads to a

> connection refused-error or more precisely to a ClientHandleException: Connection to http://localhost:8761 refused

I don't really understand where the problem is? If I don't try to connect to the server both ways work but if I try to connect only `distDocker` works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Spring Boot client app, running inside the container, is trying to reach localhost:8761, and since in the context of this Docker container 'localhost' refers to the container's address. There's nothing running on port 8761 of the container and hence you are seeing the `connection refused` error.

This might help:

Specify the location of Eureka in your client app's configuration via its `application.yml`:

```
eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: <IP-address-of-Eureka-server>/eureka/
```

The `<IP-address-of-Eureka-server>` can be either an IP address or a host name that can be resolved from *inside* the container. If you want to pass the address of your *host* VM (the host that runs your Docker container), you can pass it as an environment variable using `--env eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=xx.xx.xx.xx` form.  Something like this:

```
$ docker run ... --env eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=xx.xx.xx.xx
```

On a related note, if your Spring Boot client application also needs to register itself with Eureka, then you will need additional configuration to publish the *resolvable* host name and port of your Spring Boot app to Eureka.  You can add the following to your `application.yml`:

```
eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: <client-host>
    nonSecurePort: <client-port>
```

Where,
   `<client-host>` is the resolvable host name of the client app container; and
   `<client-port>` is the host VM's port that's bound to the exposed port of the container>

Again, you can pass these using the `--env` argument as shown above.

```
$ docker run -p 9001:8080 ... \
             --env eureka.instance.hostname=yy.yy.yy.yy \
             --env eureka.instance.nonSecurePort=9001
```

Be sure to set `yy.yy.yy.yy` to your VM's IP address.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I will see if it helps and report back

Comment: I had almost all of this in my application.yml already so it did not help but it made many things clearer for me.
I noticed, that when I use distDocker he builds a .tar-file and an extremely complicated classpath which he uses to execute the .jar-file he build out of my java-class.
buildDocker on the other hand just builds the .jar-file and executes it
so maybe the answer is somewhere hidden in the classpath

Comment: The error very clearly says that the app could not locate Eureka, and that it was trying on localhost:8761. This means that `eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone` is either not set or is set to `localhost:8761`. I'm not sure if your class path is a problem because in that case it would have most likely not even reached to that point.

Comment: You were absolutely right! Thank you!
As it turned out I had too much written in my application.yml.
I don't really understand how the error occured but after deleting some lines (I'm not sure what they were doing but I thought I needed them) everything worked

Comment: To be more precise, I had
"spring:
   profiles: docker"

written in the application.yml and after deleting this everything worked

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test in your local machine then try with host ip address. To do that use the below configuration.

```
eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://host.docker.internal:8761/eureka/
```